# .NET - Event ADD and REMOVE

Tags: c#, .net

I have never used 'add' and 'remove' when creating and using events in .NET.  Have a look at the code below:

```
public event EventHandler InitComplete
    {
        add
        {
            base.Events.AddHandler(EventInitComplete, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            base.Events.RemoveHandler(EventInitComplete, value);
        }
    }
```

I realise this is a very simple question, but where is 'value' declared? Can anyone recommend a good tutorial on use of add and remove.  I have read through a few but am still not wise enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`value` is "whatever handler is being subscribed or unsubscribed". So you can think of:

```
button.Click += HandleClick;
```

as being similar to:

```
button.add_Click(new EventHandler(HandleClick));
```

In that respect, an event is just like a property:

```
private string foo;
public string Foo
{
    get { return foo; }
    set { foo = value; }
}
```

... except that with events you have `add` and `remove` instead of `get` and `set`.

See [my article on events and delegates](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for some more information - or section 10.8 of the C# 4 language specification for the details.

Comment: thanks.  I will have a look through your tutorial.  I have edited my question with some more code as I am still confused as to why 'value' is not declared.  I realise there is probably a simple explanation.

Comment: Yes, the simple explanation is that your second code example is in VB.NET, the first in C#. If you look at the property declaration syntax in C#, you'll notice there's no value declared there either.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, thank you.  I have amended the question.  I use Visual Basic, but used a C# example in the question.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @w0051977: It's now not clear what you're actually interested in. Are you trying to understand C# event syntax, or something in VB? In VB, you use `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` and explicitly state the parameter - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt1k2w4e(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I am trying to understand how to use AddHandler and RemoveHandler with a custom event in VB.NET.  Again, sorry for the confusion.  I copied the code above from the Page class using Reflector.  There is no RaiseEvent definition in the function I provided.  Why is there no RaiseEvent definition in the Page class? I approach event handling in a different way so I am new to this.

Comment: @w0051977: C# event handlers don't declare the Raise part of an event (nor can they invoke it; it's very rarely used IMO). It's still not clear what you're really trying to achieve with this question... something concrete that you want to add to your code? Better understanding of VB? Better understanding of C#?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, my aim is a better understanding of VB.NET event handling.  I realise I should have stated VB.NET as a question tag rather than C# and provided a concrete VB.NET example.  In the Page class, the VB.NET custom events e.g. InitComplete are defined without a RaiseEvent definition.  Why is this?

Comment: @w0051977: The simple answer is "because `RaiseEvent` is optional in other languages" - basically, `Page` was probably written in C#, not VB. From what I can see, your actual question (about where `value` comes from) is entirely separate from anything about VB, given that `value` *would* be explicitly declared in VB...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I agree.  I understand now about 'value' because of your original answer and the information contained in your blog.  I am now confused why I am getting an error saying raiseevent definition is missing, as in your last comment you say this is optional.  This MSDN article seems to think it is not: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184583%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @w0051977: It's optional as far as .NET is concerned, and isn't even *available* in C#. It's required in VB, although that seems a very odd decision to me.